# Editing Javascript File

Tags: javascript

I am editing a javascript file for the first time and was wondering if someone could help point me in the right direction.

```
h&&""!=g&&(k+='<strong>Get Directions:</strong> <a href="'+g+'">'+g+"</a><br>"),
```

The code above is just a snippet from a larger file but is what I am trying to edit. I have added 'Get Directions' but now I want to remove the URL being shown in the middle of the link so that it reads "Click Here".

The +g+ is outputting an office URL.

I am unsure of how to edit the line as everything I do breaks the module.

E.g. example that does not work....

```
    h&&""!=g&&(k+='<strong>Get Directions:</strong> <a href="'+g+'">'Click Here"</a><br>"),
```

Comment: @ksav, it's the URL.

Comment: have you tried `h&&""!=g&&(k+='<strong>Get Directions:</strong> <a href="'+g+'">'+"Click here"+"</a><br>"),`

Comment: Just change `>'+g+"<` to `>Click here<` and fix the last quote: `'<strong>Get Directions:</strong> <a href="'+g+'">Click here</a><br>'`

Comment: Or just `h&&""!=g&&(k+='<strong>Get Directions:</strong> <a href="'+g+'">Click Here</a><br>'),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's confusing because you are using ' and " on the same line to enclose strings. The "Click Here" text should be inside the string like this:

```
<a href="'+g+'">Click Here</a><br>')
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your contributions! This worked so thanks :) headache over!

Comment: @Alex Banks Would be cool of you to mark this answer as correct since it seemed to help you

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
h&&""!=g&&(k+='<strong>Get Directions:</strong> <a href="'+g+'">Click here</a><br>'),
```